# Continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ preserving compactness - some clarification

Tags: analysis, continuity, compactness

My professor went over a proof of the following in class:

> Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact and $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is continuous. Then $f(A)$ is compact.

The proof (presented by my professor in class) is as follows:

> Since $f$ is continuous, the set $ \{f^{-1}(U_{i})|i \in I \}$ is an open cover for $A$. Since $A$ is compact, each open cover has a finite sub cover, hence $ \{ f^{-1}(U_{j}) | j \in I \}$ is a finite sub cover. Therefore, $ \{ U_{j} | j \in I \}$ is a finite sub cover for $f(A)$ and $f(A)$ is compact.

There are a few areas of this proof which are not quite clear to me, addressed in the four questions below (the last two are purely notational questions):

1. Does this hold for any metric space or is this just a special property of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?
2. A part of me is skeptical that this proof is sufficient. It seems that we've only shown that **one** open cover (i.e. $ \{U_{i} | i \in I \} $ )  of $f(A)$ has a finite sub cover.
3. Does it matter that we've given no explicit bound for the finite sub cover? That is, shouldn't the finite sub cover be written: $ \{ f^{-1}(U_{i})| i \in I$ and $i \leq j \}$
4. Why does each $i$ have to be in an index set $I$? Can't I just set $i \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:  Yes.  In fact, all you need is the domain to be compact and the range to be any topological space.

2:  You started with an arbitrary open cover U of F(A).   Following the above logic, you find a finite subcover of that U.  So it works for any open cover

3:  No,   the original index set isn't even necessarilly numbers or countable.   We RELABEL the particular ones we want as a finite one.  So, pick the j sets you need, and relabel each one appropriately.

4:  No,  $\mathbb N$ only works if the cover is countable.   Compactness requires for ANY open cover, not just countable covers.

Comment: Alan, can you explain why the Hausdorff condition is necessary in the proof? Because I think this result is valid for any TOPOLOGICAL space.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong...you need hausdorff for it to be a homeomorphism.  I'll fix

Comment: Careful. The image of any compact set under a continuous function is always compact in any topological space. The proof is the same as the proof above.

Comment: I was conflating this proof in my mind with the continuous+compact+hausdorff=homeomorphism proof,  its fixed now

Comment: You mean how a continuous bijection from a compact to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @Nishant Yes, that one